# Best practice for coding the server IP Address in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, ip, frontend

I'm building the frontend using Reactjs framework where I need to fetch data from node backend. At the moment, I'm manually writing out the IP addresses (as localhost), but when the application will be deployed, these IP needs to change.

So, what's the best practice for writing out the backend IP addresses in the frontend. Is it good to keep in a file and read from it?

Comment: You can use environment variables

Comment: you should not be using server Ip in api endpoints , that will cause cors problem. its best to make all api calls relative ex `/api/v1/something`. instead of `10.122.122.122:8282/api/v1/something`. use proxy server to route requests to appropriate server..

Answer (score 0):

You should work with environment variables, take a look at process.env in the nodejs docs.

I would suggest the usage of .env files, [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) is a nice package that let you define environment variables for every environment that you need. Usually you use process.env.NODE_ENV to describe in which environment your code is executed.

Comment: Thanks! I was new to this.